# auto-silencing an app by using gestures - how to?

Tags: android

I want to make an android app that will judge my body gestures and on the basis of those gestures it will silent my mobile. What libraries or which features will I have to use.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case, you can find some content on developers.google.com for touch listeners API methods. Once the set gesture event occurs, you can then use the AudioManager API to silent your phone through the app. For your reference,

[Chang Phone to Silent Mode on BroadCast Recieving in Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448223/chang-phone-to-silent-mode-on-broadcast-recieving-in-xamarin-android)